# How do you subtract two rows in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to subtract two rows in Power BI to get the difference in a row below. In the below example, I want the difference between the two numbers, not the total [image: Click to see image]

Comment: The easiest thing will be to unpivot Actual and Budget to separate columns.

Comment: Do you mind going into more detail? Unfortunately, the report needs to stay in this format.